# Figure size in matplotlib wont change. Why?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```python
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5)) 
sns.lmplot(x='raceId', y='duration', data=newdf)
plt.title('title')  
plt.show()
```

Figure won't change size. I used plt.figure(figsize()) earlier for a different plot and it worked fine. Will I need to make a new plt?

Comment: Is the target size bigger than your screen?

Comment: `sns.lmplot` is a figure-level function, creating its own figure consisting of one or more subplots.  You can use `height=.., aspect=...` to change the height and width of individual subplots.

Comment: ["Specifying figure sizes" in the tutorial](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#specifying-figure-sizes)